# Any morphism $\phi:G \rightarrow A$ to an abelian group $A$ factors uniquely through the projection $G \rightarrow G /[G,G]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

I'm doing this exercise **7(b)** in textbook *Algebra* by Saunders MacLane and Garrett Birkhoff. Could you please verify if my attempt is fine or contains logical mistakes?

[image]

Let $G$ be a group and $C$ its commutator subgroup. Prove that

- $G / C$ is abelian.
- Any morphism $\phi:G \rightarrow A$ to an abelian group $A$ factors uniquely through the projection $G \rightarrow G /C$.

---

**My attempt:**

For $a,b \in G$, we have $aC, bC \in G/C$. It follows from $b^{-1}a^{-1}ba \in C$ that $C =
 (b^{-1}a^{-1}ba)C$. Then $(aC)(bC) = (ab)C = (ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1}ba)C=(ba)C = (bC)(aC)$. Hence $G/C$ is abelian.

Next we prove that $\phi(C) = \{1\}$. For $x = b^{-1}a^{-1}ba \in C$, we have $\phi(x) = \phi(b^{-1}a^{-1}ba) = \phi(b)^{-1} \phi(a)^{-1} \phi(b) \phi(a)$. On the other hand, $A$ is abelian and thus $\phi(a)^{-1} \phi(b) = \phi(b) \phi(a)^{-1}$. Hence $\phi(x) = 1$.

To sum up, we have $C \trianglelefteq G$ and $\phi:G \rightarrow A$ a group morphism and $\phi(C) = \{1\}$. Then the result follows from *Theorem 26*.

[image]

Comment: Looks good! You'll find a proof of this result to compare to with a search like "abelianization" (which is the name given to $G/[G,G]$)

Comment: $\phi(C)=\{1\}$ can be written as $C\subseteq \operatorname{ker}\phi$

Comment: Oh yeah @ThomasAndrews. I just want to be consistent with *Theorem 26* ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have looks great! In the interest of precision, you might mention that $C$ is generated by the commutators $[a,b]$. Because of this, showing that $\phi([a,b]) = 1$ for all $a,b$ (as you did) is enough to show that $\phi_* C = \{1\}$ (as is required). This is a subtle point, though, and as long as you know that it works, that's enough.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I greatly appreciate your elaboration on that subtle point. Honestly, it's on my mind when I wrote down the proof.